# Why is my MySQL database disconnecting when running cron job?

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a job on a Databricks notebook that connects to my MySQL database on AWS RDS and inserts data. When I ran the notebook manually, I was able to connect to the endpoint URL and insert my data. Now I have my notebook running on a corn job every 30 min. The first job was successful, but every job after that failed with this error:

```
MySQLInterfaceError: MySQL server has gone away
```

I then tried to run my job manually again and I get the same error on `tweets_pdf.to_sql(name='tweets', con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)`. This is the code that is running in the Databricks notebook:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import pymysql
import os
import re
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from operator import add
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import json
import boto
import boto3
from boto.s3.key import Key
import boto.s3.connection
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinMaxScaler
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Get AWS credentials
aws_key_id = os.environ.get("accesskeyid")
aws_key = os.environ.get("secretaccesskey")

# Start spark instance
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("first") 
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

# Allow spark to access my S3 bucket
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId",aws_key_id)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey",aws_key)
config_dict = {"fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId":aws_key_id,
               "fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey":aws_key}
bucket = "diego-twitter-stream-sink"
prefix = "/2020/*/*/*/*"
filename = "s3n://{}/{}".format(bucket, prefix)

# Convert file from S3 bucket to an RDD
rdd = sc.hadoopFile(filename,
                'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat',
                'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
                'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
                conf=config_dict)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PythonWordCount").config("spark.files.overwrite","true").getOrCreate()

# Map RDD to specific columns
df = spark.read.json(rdd.map(lambda x: x[1]))
features_of_interest = ["ts", "text", "sentiment"]
df_reduce = df.select(features_of_interest)



# Convert RDD to Pandas Dataframe
tweets_pdf = df_reduce.toPandas()

engine = create_engine(f'mysql+mysqlconnector://admin:{os.environ.get("databasepassword")}@{os.environ.get("databasehost")}/twitter-data')

tweets_pdf.to_sql(name='tweets', con=engine, if_exists = 'replace', index=False)
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue? All of the database config variables are correct, the S3 bucket that PySpark is streaming from has data, and the AWS RDS is nowhere near any capacity or compute limits.

Answer (score 1):

A default [max_allowed_packets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) (4M) can cause this issue

Comment: that's probably it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet={x in bytes};